# Ruby regexp help

Tags: ruby

I need help to remove the string /* s */ (comments in .c and .h files) from some files using Ruby. Is it correct to use gsub to do this. I know that this string is always placed at the beginning av a line.

thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
str.gsub(/^\/\*.*?\*\// , '')
```

Doesn't look nice, but should do it.

Comment: Better use `.*?` instead of `.*` in there, otherwise you will remove everything between the start of the first comment and the end of the last comment within the string.